# how to get the input value of textbox by its id in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have text box its a type of number with the value 1. i want to get the value of this text box in jquery.

```
 <input type="number" value="1" name="quantity"  class="form-control quantity" id="<?= $product_id ?>" />
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.add_cart').click(function(){
  var quantity = $('#' + product_id).val();
  alert(quantity);
});
</script>
```

here the problem is if i click add to cart to with default value (i.e 1) i am getting the alert as 1. but if increase the  value of the text box value i am still getting the alert as 1. it should not be happened i want to get the incremented or decremented value. can anyone please me.

Comment: from where do you get product_id

Comment: it comes from database

Comment: I mean in your jquery code, you have `product_id`

Comment: Also you should really include all relevant code in your question

Comment: actualy i have one external scrpt.js file which is include in my file. if  i uncomment this file it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to render your product_id with php directly. Given that js file is not separated from php file.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.add_cart').click(function(){
  var quantity = $('#' + '<?= product_id ?>').val();
  alert(quantity);
});
</script>
```

Comment: How is `<?= product_id ?>` a valid id?

Comment: var quantity = $('#' + '<?= product_id ?>').val();    this is not the proper syntaxt

Comment: @noushad mohammed I said given that js file is not separated from php file. Which means php renders that part first, and then serves html. So <?= product_id ?> will be replaced with actual product_id

Answer (score 1):

why you need to create the id dynamically? if not just use

```
<input type="number" value="1" name="quantity"  class="form-control quantity" id="product_id" />
```

and in your javascript

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add_cart').click(function(){
    var quantity = $('#product_id').val();
    alert(quantity);
 });
```

Comment: product_number is the static id for input.

Comment: this is completely unnecessary answer (asking to change id), suppose if he have more than one time this input then due to same id he will got a major problem.

Comment: i am not suggesting to change the id. i am suggesting if dynamic id not needed can use static id easily.